# Applicative functors: why can fmap take a function with more than one argument?

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative

I am getting into Haskell and found the book "learn you a Haskell" most helpful. I am up to the section on [applicative functors](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors).

I am puzzled by the following as it appears in the book:

```
(\x y z -> [x, y, z]) <$> (+3) <*> (*2) <*> (/2) $ 5
```

which yields the output:

```
[8.0,10.0,2.5]
```

First of all, I have confirmed my suspicion in ghci in regards to precedence of the operators, so that the above equals the following ugly statement:

```
(((\x y z -> [x,y,z]) <$> (+3)) <*> (*2) <*> (/2)) $ 5
```

So from that it becomes clear that the first thing that happens is the `fmap` call via the `(<$>)` infix operator.

And this is the core of what boggles my mind currently.
The definition of `fmap` (here shown as infix `(<$>)`) is:

```
(<$>) :: (Functor f) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

But in the equation I am struggling with, `(\x y z -> [x, y, z])` takes three arguments, not just one. So how could the first argument of type `(a -> b)` be satisfied?

I think it might have to do with partial application / currying but I cannot figure it out. I would greatly appreciate an explanation. Hope I have formulated the question well enough.

Comment: The lambda calculus can be tricky.

Answer (score 13):

Simple answer: *there are no functions with multiple arguments in Haskell!*

There are two candidates for what you might call "dyadic function": a function that takes a (single!) tuple, and – by far prevalent in Haskell – *curried functions*. Those take just one argument, but the result is a function again.

So, to figure out what e.g. `fmap (+)` does, let's write

```
type IntF = Int -> Int

-- (+) :: Int -> IntF
-- fmap :: ( a -> b  ) ->  f a -> f b
--  e.g.:: (Int->IntF) -> f Int->f IntF
```

Test it yourself in GHCi:

> Prelude> type IntF = Int -> Int
>   Prelude> let (#) = (+) :: Int -> IntF
>   Prelude> :t fmap (#)
>   fmap (#) :: Functor f => f Int -> f IntF

Answer (score 9):

Consider a function of type

```
f :: a -> b -> c -> d
```

where `d` is any other type. Due to currying, this can be thought of as a function with the following type

```
f :: a -> (b -> c -> d)
```

i.e. a function that takes an `a` and returns  function of type `b -> c -> d`. If you apply `fmap`, you have

```
-- the type of fmap, which is also :: (a -> r) -> (f a -> f r)
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> r) -> f a -> f r

-- the type of f
f :: a -> (b -> c -> d)

-- so, setting r = b -> c -> d
fmap f :: f a -> f (b -> c -> d)
```

Which is now of the right type to be used as the left-hand argument to `(<*>)`.

Answer (score 3):

Because you can take a 3-argument function, feed it just one argument, and this results in a 2-argument function. So you're going to end up with a list of 2-argument functions. You can then apply one more argument, ending up with a list of 1-argument functions, and finally apply the last argument, whereupon you end up with a list of ordinary numbers.

Incidentally, this is *why* Haskell has curried functions. It makes it easy to write constructs like this one which work for any number of function arguments. :-)

Comment: +100 for "this is why Haskell has curried functions" --- exactly right!  It makes it easier to manipulate code calling functions with multiple arguments in a compiler, too.

Answer (score 3):

I personally find the applicative functor instance for functions a bit strange. I'll walk you through this example to try to understand intuitively what's going on:

```
>>> :t (\x y z -> [x, y, z]) <$> (+3)
... :: Num a => a -> a -> a -> [a]
>>> ((\x y z -> [x, y, z]) <$> (+3)) 1 2 3
[4,2,3]
```

This applies `(+3)` to the first parameter of the inner function. The other 2 outer parameters are passed to the inner function unmodified.

Let's add an applicative:

```
>>> :t (\x y z -> [x, y, z]) <$> (+3) <*> (*2)
... :: Num a => a -> a -> [a]
>>> ((\x y z -> [x, y, z]) <$> (+3) <*> (*2)) 1 2
[4,2,2]
```

This applies `(+3)` to the first argument as before. With the applicative, the first outer parameter (`1`) is applied `(*2)` and passed as the second parameter of the inner function. The second outer parameter is passed unmodified to the inner function as its third parameter.

Guess what happens when we use another applicative:

```
>>> :t (\x y z -> [x, y, z]) <$> (+3) <*> (*2) <*> (/2)
... :: Fractional a => a -> [a]
>>> (\x y z -> [x, y, z]) <$> (+3) <*> (*2) <*> (/2) $ 1
[4.0,2.0,0.5]
```

3 applications to the same parameter passed as 3 arguments to the inner function.

It's not theoretically solid explanation, but it can give an intuition about how the applicative instance of functions works.

Answer (score 2):

### Background

Let's start with the definition of the `<*>` and `pure` for functions as an instance of `Applicative`. For `pure`, it will take any garbage value, and return `x`. For `<*>`, you can think of it as applying `x` to `f`, getting a new function out of it, then applying it to the output of `g x`.

```
instance Applicative ((->) r) where  
    pure x = (\_ -> x)  
    f <*> g = \x -> f x (g x)
```

Now, let's look at the definition of `<$>`. It is just an infix version of `fmap`.

```
(<$>) :: (Functor f) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b  
f <$> x = fmap f x
```

Recall that `fmap` has the following implementation:

```
instance Functor ((->) r) where  
    fmap f g = (\x -> f (g x))
```

### Proving that `f <$> x` is just `pure f <*> x`

Let's start with `pure f <*> x`. Replace `pure f` with `(\_ -> f)`.

```
pure f <*> x 
= (\_ -> f) <*> x
```

Now, let's apply the definition of `<*>`, which is `f <*> g = \q -> f q (g q)`.

```
(\_ -> f) <*> x
= \q -> (\_ -> f) q (x q)
```

Notice we can simplify `(\_ -> f) q` as just `f`. The function takes in whatever value we give it, and returns `f`.

```
\q -> (\_ -> f) q (x q)
= \q -> f (x q)
```

That looks just like our definition of `fmap`! And the `<$>` operator is just infix `fmap`.

```
\q -> f (x q)
= fmap f x
= f <$> x
```

Let's keep this in mind: `f <$> g` is just `pure f <*> g`.

### Understanding `(\x y z -> [x, y, z]) <$> (+3) <*> (*2) <*> (/2) $ 5`

First step is to rewrite the left side of expression to use `<*>` instead of `<$>`. Using what we just proved in in the previous section:

```
(\x y z -> [x, y, z]) <$> (+3)
= pure (\x y z -> [x, y, z]) <*> (+3)
```

So the full expression becomes

```
pure (\x y z -> [x, y, z]) <*> (+3) <*> (*2) <*> (/2) $ 5
```

Let's simplify the first operator using the definition of `<*>`

```hs
pure (\x y z -> [x, y, z]) <*> (+3)
= \a -> f a (g a) --substitute f and g
= \a -> pure (\x y z -> [x, y, z]) a ((+3) a)
```

Now let's substitute `pure x` with `(\_ -> x)`. Observe that `a` becomes the garbage value that's used as `_`, and is consumed to return the function `(\x y z -> [x, y, z])`.

```
\a -> (\_-> (\x y z -> [x, y, z])) a ((+3) a)
= \a -> (\x y z -> [x, y, z]) ((+3) a)
```

Now let's look back at the full expression, and tackle the next `<*>`. Again, let's apply the definition of `<*>`.

```
(\a -> (\x y z -> [x, y, z]) ((+3) a)) <*> (*2)
= \b -> (\a -> (\x y z -> [x, y, z]) ((+3) a)) b ((*2) b)
```

Finally, let's repeat this one last time for the final `<*>`.

```
(\b -> (\a -> (\x y z -> [x, y, z]) ((+3) a)) b ((*2) b)) <*> (/2)
= \c -> (\b -> (\a -> (\x y z -> [x, y, z]) ((+3) a)) b ((*2) b)) c ((/2) c)
```

Notice that it's a function that takes a single value. We'll feed it `5`.

```
(\c -> (\b -> (\a -> (\x y z -> [x, y, z]) ((+3) a)) b ((*2) b)) c ((/2) c)) 5
(\5 -> (\b -> (\a -> (\x y z -> [x, y, z]) ((+3) a)) b ((*2) b)) 5 ((/2) 5))
       (\b -> (\a -> (\x y z -> [x, y, z]) ((+3) a)) b ((*2) b)) 5 (2.5   )
       (\5 -> (\a -> (\x y z -> [x, y, z]) ((+3) a)) 5 ((*2) 5))   (2.5   )
              (\a -> (\x y z -> [x, y, z]) ((+3) a)) 5 (10    )    (2.5   )
              (\5 -> (\x y z -> [x, y, z]) ((+3) 5))   (10    )    (2.5   )           
                     (\x y z -> [x, y, z]) (8     )    (10    )    (2.5   )         

(\x y z -> [x, y, z]) (8) (10) (2.5)                     
= [8, 10, 2.5]
```

And that's how we get the final answer.

Answer (score 1):

For your question, especially "...takes three arguments, not just one...", it's the topic of `applicative functor` and it doesn't matter the functor. Hence, simply seeing the definition of fmap doesn't help to understand the confusion.

Before clarifying your confusion, please allow me to introduce the functor and applicative functor again.

### Functions Are Functors

As the definition refers and everyone knows, a functor *allows one to apply a function to values inside a generic type without changing the structure of the generic type*. The implication is functions are also functors, which could be represented as `(->) r` according to the [source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-1088).

```hs
instance Functor ((->) r) where
    fmap = (.)
```

It hints a `function` could be applied as a `functor` by another function, no matter how many arguments are required.
For example, `(+1)` is a functor, any function could be applied to it if the first argument is the same type (note that every function technically only has one input and output type).

```
ghci> f1 = fmap (+1) (*2)
ghci> :t f1
f1 :: Num b => b -> b
ghci> f2 = fmap (+) (*2)
ghci> :t f2
f2 :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Here, intrusion follows your mind. Any function applied to a functor(also a function) always keeps the same arguments. That's undoubtedly correct, and the following calculation outputs are logical:

```
ghci> f1 2
5
ghci> f2 2 1
5
```

More generally, in the function way to express a functor, it will be:

```hs
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
fmap :: (a -> b) -> ((->) c a) -> ((->) c b)
fmap :: (a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> (c -> b)
```

The conduction is, after applying, the output of `c->` requires an input, and the `b` requires the other inputs.

### Functions Are Applicative Functors

As function is first class in Haskell, a function could be applied to a functor. After that, to solve the problem of applying a functor that holds a function with another functor, the applicative functor came into being.

```hs
class (Functor f) => Applicative f where  
    pure :: a -> f a  
    (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

To understand the `<*>` correctly, it's essential to know that functions are functors.
Then, see the signature of `<*>`, which is slightly different from `fmap`; however, that's why the arguments could decrease.

```hs
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
class (Functor f) => Applicative f where  
    pure :: a -> f a  
    (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Let's see `fmap` firstly, the `Nb` refers to the number of function arguments in b, and functor `f` always takes `1` argument. As a result, both `a->b` and `f b` require `1+Nb` arguments.
However, the `<*>` merge two functors to one, which means the original function `f (a -> b)` requires `1+1+Nb` arguments, but the returned value receives `1+Nb` arguments.
As a result, the arguments in the output minus one when applying(<*>) happened. It's lost because **applicative functors are merged**.
This explains why the arguments decrease(from three to one).

Let's take a further step. How could the argument number decrease? Only `currying` could achieve it.  The explanation above shows why the arguments decrease while `<*>` is called if we say the signature from left to right.

Now, fold the `f b` to `f (a->b) -> f a` and pass an input to `f b`, then the `(f b) input` will be `f (input -> b) -> f input`. As the `f (a -> b )` could always be folded out, finally, the full arguments are currying one by one as the fold goes.

So, your question `(\x y z -> [x, y, z]) <$> (+3) <*> (*2) <*> (/2) $ 5` will be executed somehow like this:

```
(\x y z -> [x, y, z]) <$> (+3) <*> (*2) <*> (/2) $ 5
= (\x y -> [x , y, 2.5]) <$> (+3) <*> (*2)$ 5
= (\x -> [x, 10, 2.5] <$> (+3) $ 5
= [8, 10, 2.5]
```